# Resetting search criteria in a razor page with another button that is not the submit button of the form

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page that I developed based off of this [Add Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2) tutorial by Microsoft.

Inside of the form on the page I have a Filter button which calls the OnGetAsync() method query string params and is working great. However, I added a reset button to the form as well. The reset button clears the form fields as expected, but without using JavaScript/jQuery how can I make another call that will end up with no query string params so the user's search is reset?

I was researching using handlers. Is this what I would use? Or can I have the reset button call the OnGetAsync as well, but with no query string params?

Answer (score 1):

For Razor Page query, it passes the parameters by query string like below:

`http://localhost:64454/Movies?MovieGenre=Comedy&SearchString=`

For clearing the query string, you could try:

```
<form>
    <p>
        <select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
        Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        <a asp-route-MovieGenre="" asp-route-SearchString="" class="btn btn-primary">ReSet</a>
    </p>
</form>
```